# In Rails 5, how do I create a many-to-many association that is polymorphic in both directions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 namespaced user classes - `Users::SuperAdminUser`, `Users::AdminUser`, and `Users::StandardUser` and currently 2 namespaced user group classes - `UserGroups::Team` and `UserGroups::Projects`. I want to create a many-to-many polymorphic relationship in both directions (e.g. an admin user could belong to multiple teams and multiple projects, and a team could contain multiple standard users, multiple super admin users, etc.)

I've tried a few approaches, such as adapting and mixing these solutions (all of which are polymorphic in only one direction), but I end up getting lost in the weeds:

[many to many polymorphic association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077728/many-to-many-polymorphic-association)

[Rails: has_many through not returning correctly with namespaced models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539202/rails-has-many-through-not-returning-correctly-with-namespaced-models)

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=6

https://utkukaynarblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/polymorphic-has_many-through-associations-in-ruby-on-rails/

I primarily utilized the approach of the last link. I tried to make the association polymorphic in the other direction by adding an 'Enlistable' concern representing the user classes as a compliment to the existing 'Memberable' concern which represents the user group classes (team and project, in my case), but to no avail.

Currently, I have user models that look like this:

```
module Users
  class SuperAdminUser < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'users_super_admin_users'

    include UserGroups::Enlistable

    has_many :user_groups_memberships
    has_many :user_groups_teams,    through: :memberships, source: :memberable, source_type: 'UserGroups::Team'
    has_many :user_groups_projects, through: :memberships, source: :memberable, source_type: 'UserGroups::Project'

  end
end
```

team/project classes that look like this:

```
module UserGroups
  class Team < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'user_groups_teams'

    include Memberable

    has_many :user_groups_memberships
    has_many :users_super_admin_users, through: :memberships, source: :enlistable, source_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser'
    has_many :users_admin_users,       through: :memberships, source: :enlistable, source_type: 'Users::AdminUser'
    has_many :users_standard_users,    through: :memberships, source: :enlistable, source_type: 'Users::StandardUser'

  end
end
```

a membership class that looks like this:

```
module UserGroups
  class Membership < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'user_groups_memberships'

    belongs_to :enlistable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :memberable, polymorphic: true

  end
end
```

enlistable/memberable concerns that look like this:

```
module UserGroups
  module Enlistable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      has_many :memberships, as: :enlistable, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :memberables, through: :memberships
    end    
  end
end
```

and a membership migration that looks like this:

```
class CreateUserGroupsMembership < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_groups_memberships do |t|

      t.string  :enlistable_type
      t.integer :enlistable_id
      t.string  :memberable_type
      t.integer :memberable_id

      t.references :enlistable, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'index_user_groups_memberships_on_enlistable_type_and_id' }
      t.references :memberable, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'index_user_groups_memberships_on_memberable_type_and_id' }

      t.timestamps  null: false

    end
  end
end
```

Everything migrates fine and I seed the database with multiples of each user class as well as the team and project classes. But I'm stumped from there. If I have a particular user, let's say `Users::SuperAdminUser.first`, I want to create and access it's associations, i.e. assign it to a team and list the teams to which they belong. How would I set it up to do that and, once set up, how would I perform those actions? One of the keys here is being able to accomplish this while taking into account the namespacing.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I have a solution, one that works with namespaces and is flexible enough that you can create a bi-directional, many-to-many, polymorphic association between any two sets of namespaced classes within your application. It automatically generates the reverse association, deletes any associations that involve a model when the model is deleted, and insures there are no duplicate records of associations. I don't know how optimal it is or whether or not it will scale well, but it seems to work exactly how I need it to. I would appreciate feedback, though, on any foreseen problems or potential pitfalls.

**~/app/models/users/super_admin_user.rb**

```
module Users
  class SuperAdminUser < ApplicationRecord

    include Polymorpher
    self.table_name = 'users_super_admin_users'

    Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/user_groups/*.rb'].map { |f| File.path(f).to_s.sub(Rails.root.to_s + '/app/models/', '').chomp('.rb').camelize.constantize }
    associated_user_groups = UserGroups.constants.map { |user_groups_constant| UserGroups.const_get(user_groups_constant).to_s }

    has_many_through_polymorphs(associated_user_groups)

  end
end
```

I have additional classes for `admin_user` and `standard_user` which are identical with the obvious exceptions of change of class and table names. I omit them for brevity sake.

**~/app/models/user_groups/project.rb**

```
module UserGroups
  class Project < ApplicationRecord

    include Polymorpher
    self.table_name = 'user_groups_projects'

    Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/users/*.rb'].map { |f| File.path(f).to_s.sub(Rails.root.to_s + '/app/models/', '').chomp('.rb').camelize.constantize }
    associated_users = Users.constants.map { |users_constant| Users.const_get(users_constant).to_s }

    has_many_through_polymorphs(associated_users)

  end
end
```

I, once again, have an additional class for `team` which is identical, also with the obvious exceptions of change of class and table names.

**~/app/models/relationships/relationship.rb**

```
module Relationships
  class Relationship < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'relationships_relationships'

    after_create { |relationship| create_reverse_relationship(relationship) }

    belongs_to :origination_class, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :destination_class, polymorphic: true

    validates :origination_class_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:origination_class_type, :destination_class_id, :destination_class_type] }

    private

    def create_reverse_relationship(relationship)
      reverse_origination    = relationship.destination_class_type.constantize.find(relationship.destination_class_id)
      reverse_destination    = relationship.origination_class_type.constantize.find(relationship.origination_class_id)
      association_attribute  = relationship.origination_class_type.underscore.gsub('/','_').pluralize

      if !Relationships::Relationship.exists?(origination_class_type: reverse_origination.class.to_s,
                                              origination_class_id:   reverse_origination.id,
                                              destination_class_type: reverse_destination.class.to_s,
                                              destination_class_id:   reverse_destination.id)
        eval "reverse_origination.#{ association_attribute } << reverse_destination"
      end
    end

  end
end
```

**~/app/models/concerns/polymorpher.rb**

```
module Polymorpher
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_destroy { |origin_object| delete_destination_relationships(origin_object.class.to_s, origin_object.id) }

    def delete_destination_relationships(object_class_name, object_id)
      Relationships::Relationship.where(destination_class_type: object_class_name, destination_class_id: object_id).delete_all
    end

  end

  module ClassMethods

    def has_many_through_polymorphs(associated_classes)

      has_many :relationships_relationships,
               class_name: 'Relationships::Relationship',
               as: :origination_class,
               dependent: :destroy

      associated_classes.each do |associated_class|
        has_many associated_class.underscore.gsub('/','_').pluralize.to_sym,
                 through:     :relationships_relationships,
                 source:      :destination_class,
                 source_type: associated_class
      end

    end

  end

end
```

**~/db/migrate/20170127022550_create_users_super_admin_user.rb**

```
class CreateUsersSuperAdminUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users_super_admin_users do |t|
      t.string :email
    end
  end
end
```

All of remaining migrations for the `Users` and `UserGroups` namespaced classes are virtually identical to this with the exception of migrations for `UserGroups` classes having a `:name` attribute rather than an `:email` attribute.

**~/db/migrate/20170127036200_create_relationships_relationship.rb**

```
class CreateRelationshipsRelationship < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change

    create_table :relationships_relationships do |t|

      t.references :origination_class, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'index_relationships_relationships_on_origination_type_and_id' }
      t.references :destination_class, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'index_relationships_relationships_on_destination_type_and_id' }

      t.timestamps null: false

    end

    add_index :relationships_relationships,
             [:origination_class_type, :origination_class_id, :destination_class_type, :destination_class_id],
               unique: true,
               name: 'index_relationships_relationships_unique_combo_of_all_columns'

  end
end
```

**Note:** This solution was inspired by the solution within this exchange:

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/203838

I did not duplicate it, however, because I couldn't have my user models inherit from another model (e.g. PolyRecord in the link example) since they will ultimately inherit from the Devise user model.